# Content load with .load dont go when form is serialized

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

Well, I load content depending on the option selected in a combobox. It works fine, the problem is when I submit ( serialize )  the form, the content loaded dont go within.

```
$("#enviar_excluir").click(function(){
    $("#resposta_excluir").load("<?php echo $table.'/'.$table; ?>_sql.php",$("#calendario_excluir").serialize(),function(){
        $("#enviar_excluir").show(300,function(){alert('Good Job');});
    });
});
```

I Basically load an amount of checkboxes.

What is the problem ?

Comment: You know that you are disclosing database details to users on the internet with `...ad("<?php echo $table.'/'.$table; ?>_sql....`, inviting for an SQL injection?

Comment: yes, but it is an internal part of a system, so a mind that the owners of the system will not try to access database if they have access for free... but thanks for the advertisement.